# Why hast thou forsaken me, Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, users

I have been a happy Stack Overflow user for the past years. I never bothered to register, because all the questions that I would have asked, *had already been asked*. And those questions all had answers, nicely presented for me savor  them.

Until that one day, not long ago, where I had one question that I could not find on Stack Overflow. I thought it to be a rather trivial question, since it boils down to "Where do I have to put this one file?".

So I signed up, asked my questions and expected the answers to come in a couple of minutes, maybe hours. But they were not coming. Neither did comments about how I could maybe clarify my questions.

I searched how I could make the question more attractive. And I found the concept of bounties. But my credit card would not be of any help here, I had to gain reputation first.

So I joined the game of questions. And I learned, that this truly is a game. A game, not unfamiliar to me. Having played MMORPGs since the late 90s, I instantly remembered the days when you were sitting in front of your screen, waiting for this one rare monster to spawn. And when it spawned, you had to be quick, because there were always a bunch of other players around that tried the same. As these monsters' lives were usually very short, so are unanswered, but easily answerable questions at Stack Overflow.

Not only once was I beaten by someone else, who was just quicker than me. The dreaded "A new answer has been posted" while typing my answer became quickly a nightmare.

But I have made it, I gained one hundred reputation points, just to realize, that I would have to wait a few days before I could add the bounty.

And so I waited. But still, my heart was alight with hope. Because I was sure, when I would add the bounty, the answers would come.

But they did not. Neither did comments, asking for more clarification.

I wonder. Did I misunderstand the concept of Stack Overflow?

Is it not the place, where no open questions exist?

I am confused. And sad.

I do not know what to believe any more.

Why hast thou forsaken me, Stack Overflow?

[Where do gradle unit tests for Google app engine expect persistence.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230881/where-do-gradle-unit-tests-for-google-app-engine-expect-persistence-xml)

Comment: Your question goes to the bottom of the "featured" list when you add a bounty. Give it some time, as the bounty moves closer to ending, your question will move closer to the top of the list. Have a little bit of patience. Stack Overflow hasn't forsaken you yet. :)

Comment: You may need to wait for answers to come after a bounty is offered. There are still 6 days left... I find that usually when I offer a bounty, interest comes at about 3 to 4 days after offering it.

Comment: Sometimes, when you ask rather complex questions about new technology, it can be hard to get an answer. Stack Overflow hasn't forsaken you, you are just ahead of the curve :)

Comment: Worth noting, having added the link to your question here, you're bound to get more eyeballs on your question rather quickly now. _Be warned:_ While this can be a good thing, it _can_ backfire if your question isn't up to snuff. (At first glance, it looks pretty okay to me. You can remove the "Edit:" part of your SO question, though. Not really needed, and it looks like your question will flow just fine without it.)

Comment: I did remove the Edit: part. Wasn't sure whether this is the accepted meta or not, because I have been seeing it alot in other questions.

Comment: A lot of people do add the "Edit" and "Update" clauses in, but really, your question should be able to flow without that. After all, if you edit your question, you get that nifty little "edited x ago" link at the bottom, which shows exactly what you changed. :) So a lot of people do it, but it's really not needed.

Comment: You somehow made reading this post incredibly captivating, well done. A struggle we can all relate to.

Comment: Code blocks around file paths. Sure thing! Every little bit helps :)

Comment: @itchee: if at the end of the bounty period you still haven't had a satisfying answer, give me a ping and I will put a bigger one on it.

Comment: This raises a number of excellent points about the difficulty in finding answers to non-easy questions, all of which have certainly been raised before; there's almost too much activity on Stack Overflow... However, bravo! Please stick around; this site _is_ worth it, despite some difficulties, and this post is a fantastic question.

Comment: I have the same problem. All my very little reputation comes from answers because I don't ask questions other have asked and others have asked, well, everything. So I ask and answer small corner cases, never getting an answer to my questions. SO is great for obvious questions and answers: ask an obvious question and you'll be upvoted to a thousand rep. Ask a non-obvious question -- something nobody else has asked (because you searched before asking) -- and you'll answer it yourself for no rep. S/O is great for obvious questions. For others, yeah, it's fair to say you're forsaken.

Comment: to be fair this might be an easy but rather special question

Comment: I'm amused by reading through this question and its comments and then seeing `"1 new answer to this question"` at the bottom. :) As far as your problem is concerned, while SO does have many, many great answers, there are some questions that are just obscure and never get answered. I should know, having asked a number of them. :) On [su], I earned the "tumbleweed" badge (no answers, comments, or votes for a week) for my first question there (and, months later, it still has none.) - haha

Comment: Yesterday, after I went to bed, skullkid posted an answer to my question. It got downvoted to -3. But as it turns out, the answer is correct, albeit at first glance it looked strange. Maybe some mod can fix his grammar and spelling and make it look more proper. Poor skullkid.

Comment: Not it is not. Because I did everything (clear title, tags, bounty etc...) before asking the question. Btw, one valid answer would be: "Write a lengthy text in meta to draw attention to  your question" :)

Comment: `Not only once was I beaten by someone else, who was just quicker than me` - you've misunderstood the concept of Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange). The whole network is gamified, this is what makes it unique (other than the copycat sites). Answering a question before any others do so is part of the experience.

Comment: @itchee: it *is* a duplicate, though, even if you already did all that the post recommend. But note that being closed as a duplicate is not A Bad Thing. (I think adding your suggestion to that post would lead to a flurry of "please answr these questionz URGENT!!! URGENT!!!" to meta. Do we want that?)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Stack Overflow hasn't forsaken you. You just have to wait a little longer for answers to have their attention brought to your post.

When you add a bounty to a question, your question is added to the "Featured" tab. There are a number of questions with bounties on them at any given time, and they are sorted from oldest bounty to newest bounty. Thus, the bounties about to expire are on the first page, top of the list.

Right now, there are a couple hundred bounties in all tags.

> [image: 382 bounties]

That's a lot of bounties. Thankfully, these can be narrowed down by filtering on a tag. There are a lot less Java questions with bounties, so if someone is searching the bountied questions on only the Java tag, you've got a lot better chance to be seen.

> [image: 32 Java bounties]

Right now, however, with 6 days left in your bounty, your question is to the back of the list. Given a couple more days, I'm sure you'll start to get more attention on your question. Now that you've linked it from Meta Stack Overflow, you'll get more attention as well.

So, just be patient, answer any clarifying comments asked of you, and I hope you continue to contribute content to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Some questions are just **too hard to be answered right away**. For example, if they are about some deep technical details into which no one wants to dig [for free] and no one (yet) already did a research. For example, **these questions are not going to have an answer** [soon], too:

- [Android custom XferMode / PorterDuff.Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29160732/1418097)
- [How to use mozjpeg library/executables on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26961807/1418097)
- [Is it possible to use SQLite.NET with immutable record types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27890099/1418097)
- [Is there a way to allow user to select text from many `EditText`s in a row (which are in ListView)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25151761/1418097)

We have to deal with it.

Comment: Definitely worth noting that popular questions are fought over, while arcane ones may take some time.  Ironically, you beat me to writing this exact answer.

Comment: I see what you did there... nice job tricking me into answering one of your questions. I don't like the blatant self-promotion, but you did a good job hiding it.

Answer (score 6):

Others have addressed well the questions of bounty and how the more esoteric questions can be difficult to answer. As far as the "game" of StackOverflow goes, you don't have to play the game. I certainly don't, and I don't feel seriously disadvantaged as a consequence.

I don't have time to sit and watch the new questions, nor even look closely at all of the questions. But even checking in two or three times a day, skimming through the *unanswered* questions (*), looking for ones that I feel like I have the ability to contribute a useful, informed answer, or at least offer comments that can help the question be improved by the person who posted it, I find plenty of questions to answer. Reputation follows naturally.

Of course, that does mean that you can't just limit yourself to "easily answered" questions. Yes, those will all be answered by the time you show up.

Yes, in terms of the reputation race, there are skewing effects. "Quick-draw" (i.e. first to answer, especially the easier questions) can boost a person's reputation accumulation. Similarly, there's the "pioneer effect"; long-time StackOverflow contributors benefit from broadly-referenced answers, and "cornering the market" on the more fundamental questions and answers.

Oh well. Life's not fair; pioneers often gain the most, but that's in return for being there at the beginning and making the effort to develop a raw resource, so that later arrivals see lush, green pastures. Fast-answerers help make the site more responsive.

But the rest of us can still contribute, and can still benefit from those contributions. It just takes a little more patience. Though, to be clear: I probably only even view 20-30 questions each day, out of the several hundred posted each day under the one tag I'm following, and of those most are unanswerable (duplicates, poorly worded, lack good code examples, etc.). I'd guess I actually *answer* only between 1 and 5 questions per day (averaging two or three). But even at that pitiful rate, I'd guess you'd be able to earn 100 rep for your bounty in just a week or so, assuming you are actually providing good answers.

So, don't despair. Answer what you can, when you can, and try to have patience about gaining enough reputation to open some of the doors on the site, as well as with respect to getting answers for questions that are not easily answered.

**(*)** (Which admittedly overlooks many questions that I might be able to answer in a way that is better than — and in some cases *much* better than — any of the existing answers. This is one of the less-than-ideal aspects of StackOverflow: *any* answer, even a bad one, has the unfortunate effect of suppressing at least some of the future views of the question, which hurts the question's chances of getting a really good answer)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it not the place, where no open questions exist?

False. Open questions do exist on Stack Overflow, although it's a small part of the total.

But the fact that you are among the select few that search thoroughly before asking a question, also means that the answer isn't going to be very obvious, so there is a smaller audience that can answer your question, and it may take a while before the right person finds it (although the Meta-effect certainly has helped you).

So, annoying as that may be, I think it's kind of a compliment if your question doesn't get answered within the same day, let alone within 5 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

It seems distinctly questionable whether a bounty here is really worth more than a paper towel.

If you ask a question and someone knows the answer, boy howdy -- they're gonna answer it.

If you ask a question and someone thinks that it's interesting and knows how to find the answer -- ditto.

When you set a bounty, you are hypothesizing the existence of a person who, on the one hand, does not already know the answer; on the second hand, does not find it intrinsically interesting enough to go find it for you; and on the third hand, is motivated by magic stackoverflow beans to go find it for you.

Personally, I don't believe in those people, but my skepticism is not necessarily well-justified.

Comment: I think you're missing a third category: people that know or may want to search the answer, but haven't seen the question. I'd say that this is the biggest audience a bounty tries to reach.

Comment: I've found questions because I decided to check the "Featured" tab. The extra rep wasn't necessarily what motivated me, but it does work. I'm one of the people that @JeroenVannevel is talking about.