# Why did my question only get 18 views?

Tags: support, questions

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259842/custom-run-debug-in-x-command-plugin-for-visual-studio) on March 25. Yesterday, I checked the question and was surprised to note that it had only received 7 views, most of whom were probably coworkers to whom I'd send the link.

So I added a +250 bounty to try to attract more views. Today I looked at the question again and noted that it still has only received 18 views. What gives -- why the low view count, and what can I do to increase the visibility of my question in the hopes of getting a good answer?

Comment: The "featured" tab sorts oldest bounty first.

Comment: Apparently people more people either didn't see the question, or didn't consider the question interesting enough at a glance to look into.  What more are you expecting us to tell you?

Comment: the title is a little muddled and one of the important things to attracting views.  Perhaps second in importance once to Tags, for me.  Assuming plugins can be in at least VB or C#, a language tag might not hurt.

Comment: Views pick up as the question gets closer to having its bounty expire.  There are 391 questions with bounties ( http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured ) which gives [8 pages of results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=8&sort=featured). Don't expect people to go too far into that on the first day.

Comment: @Servy If I knew what I was expecting you to tell me, I wouldn't have posted the question. All I know is that 18 views seems shockingly low -- I'd have guessed that if the SO engine had ever actually displayed a link to my question anywhere, it would very quickly receive more than 18 views given the millions of hits on SO every day. But I may be mistaken. Hence me asking the question, which was "*why the low view count, and what can I do to increase the visibility*?"

Comment: @TypeIA Most of those views are people looking for something in parituclar, not people looking at every single question, and there are many thousands of questions asked every single day.  Not every single one can get thousands of views in a day.  If people weren't interested in it, then people weren't interested in it.

Comment: I have a question posted last September, with some popular tags (like c#, .net etc.). And it has 25 views now... If this could cheer you up :)

Comment: Thank you for the information about old bounties -- that's good to know.

Comment: *"don't really know where to start"* is generally not a good SO question; if not for the bounty I would have voted to close.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, that's true, but I don't think it will affect the view-count. As user need to view it before make such decision.

Comment: @Bolu true! I suppose that my point was that extra views might not necessarily lead to a good answer, as the OP hopes...

Comment: Poor proxy, but of the other two questions sharing the three tags of yours one got 33 views in a year and the other 88 in ten months.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer here: [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288854/why-hast-thou-forsaken-me-stack-overflow/288861#288861](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288854/why-hast-thou-forsaken-me-stack-overflow/288861#288861).  Bounties take time before they generate views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Question views adhere to a [log-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with a mode around 40:

[image]

What that means is that most questions do not get thousands or even hundreds of views. [Bounties *do* help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238906/1438), but not necessarily right away. I found your question on page 6 of the featured question list:

[image: Featured questions]

As you can see, your question is not particularly unloved. One question on that page had 1k views, a few more had several hundred, and the rest of the 50 question sample were right in the range of your question. The questions with more views tended to be far older than the others. The 1k question was posed on June 12, 2013, for instance.

This image also give you a hint about how to attract more views:

1. Titles take a disportionate importance in question lists. Editing your title would dramatically improve your odds of getting views, votes, and answers.
2. Tags also have outweighed importance for people looking at a bunch of questions. Thanks to [favorite and ignored tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics), some people won't see your question in the list and others will see it highlighted. (From what I can tell, your question is tagged appropriately. But this is a common problem.)
3. The very first sentence or two should have as much information as possible. Repeating the question in the title, adding a greeting, and including unnecessary context obscures the meat of the question. If you want attention from casual viewers, it's best to front-load your post.

Answer (score 14):

Your question title and tags were pretty effective at scaring SO users away.  There are not that many SO users that answer questions like this.  Visual Studio plugin development is pretty esoteric, getting 7 views is not abnormal.

Putting a bounty on a question does not produce results instantly.  You are now at the bottom of a list with 394 tough questions that only a subset of SO users look at.  You don't generally will see view activity until you rise towards the top of that list.  That will take another 3 days, give or take.

Do not expect miracles.  You are asking for a tutorial that cannot assume any prior knowledge.  The subject is worth a fat book, highly doubtful that anybody is going to write one for you.  The only real hope you have is somebody posting a "don't do that, do this instead" answer.  Inspire him to post that answer by opening that door in your question, you assume too much about how it should work.  Which is not a plugin.