# Should I repost a relevant, upvoted question without answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I only have 61 reputation and the bounty feature is available at 75 rep. So should I repost my question to get more views?

Comment: I removed the specific question link because it is actually not relevant to your question (!). This way, any answers are useful for others with a similar problem.

Comment: Further reading: [How do I draw attention to a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276326/how-do-i-draw-attention-to-a-question) (lots of useful comments) and [Why hast thou forsaken me, Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288854/why-hast-thou-forsaken-me-stack-overflow) (to be honest, a duplicate of [What do I do if my question has received no answers or comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261078/2564301) but with a much better title).

Comment: I'll be looking into those questions... I can see why you deleted the link. I added it to prove that the question existed and to add further details to the post. Now since an answer has been given such details might not be needed anymore. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14):

No.

To get more attention for your question you should:

1. Edit it to include any new information you may have discovered since you posted the question.
2. Use the share link to post in other forums, Facebook, Google+, etc. to see if you can get some new eyes on the post.
3. Post a bounty when you do reach the 75 rep threshold.

Comment: Anyway, [the privilige is as 75](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), so not too far away.

Comment: I would add a stipulation to #1: if there is nothing to add, do not edit *just to bump it up*. That is plain annoying. If you have nothing to add, leave it as it is. Perhaps the Field Experts for your tags are enjoying their weekend AFK and will only see it when they browse their favorite tags later.

Comment: @Jongware indeed. That's why I was specific in the type of information you should add.

Answer (score -2):

In general case, no.

But:

1. Sometimes it is possible, that you found the same question, but in a significantly differing context. If there is no answer for the original question, maybe an indirect solution could exist in your specific situation.
2. The way to the solution (answer) could have multiple steps. Part the problem into smaller, more specific fragments, and ask the first.

*In best case, if you get an answer to the partial problem, adding your own research, maybe you can even answer the original question, too.*

Simple reformulation is not okay, your question will be closed as duplicate. When you ask a question, you can see a popup with its possible duplicates. This popup is also visible for the reviewers deciding if it is a duplicate, or not.